# Why is my PHP MySQL Database not connecting?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to read some data from my Database in MySQL which i created via PHPmyAdmin. it seems that i can connect to it but i cannot do mysqli_query cause it's always showing a error message.

I tried looking on other Q & A but nothing seems to fix my problem, i just do not know what i am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me?

this is my index.php

```
<?php
                $adCounter = 0;

                //require_once ('conf.php');
                // die Konstanten auslagern in eigene Datei
                // die dann per require_once ('konfiguration.php'); 
                // geladen wird.

                // Damit alle Fehler angezeigt werden
                error_reporting(E_ALL);

                // Zum Aufbau der Verbindung zur Datenbank
                // die Daten erhalten Sie von Ihrem Provider
                define ( 'MYSQL_HOST', '');//i deletet those data for security reasons

                // bei XAMPP ist der MYSQL_Benutzer: root
                define ( 'MYSQL_BENUTZER',  ''); //i deletet those data for security reasons
                define ( 'MYSQL_KENNWORT',  '');//i deletet those data for security reasons

                define ( 'MYSQL_DATENBANK', '');//i deletet those data for security reasons         // für unser Bsp. nennen wir die DB oglasi

                $db_link = mysqli_connect (MYSQL_HOST,              //$db_link = mysqli_connect          mysqli_select_db
                                           MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                                           MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                                           MYSQL_DATENBANK);
                if ( $db_link )
                {
                    echo 'Good: Veza uspesno postavljena sa Serverom: ';
                    print_r( $db_link);

                }
                else
                {
                    // hier sollte dann später dem Programmierer eine
                    // E-Mail mit dem Problem zukommen gelassen werden
                    die('nije mogucce postaviti vezu sa Serverom: ' . mysqli_error());
                }

                //damit sprska slova nicht vorkommen 
                mysqli_set_charset($db_link, 'utf8');


                $sql = "SELECT * MYSQL_DATENBANK ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30";

                $db_erg = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
                if ( ! $db_erg )
                {
                  die('Error: Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error());
                }

                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";

                while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg))
                {

                    echo '<span style="color:ORANGE; font-size:18px;">';
                        echo "<td>". $zeile['date'];
                    echo '</span>';
                    echo '<span style="color:orange; font-size:;">';
                        echo' (Godina-Mesec-Dan)';
                    echo '</span>';
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo '<strong>';
                        echo "<td>". $zeile['title'] . ": ";
                    echo '</strong>';

                    echo "<td>". $zeile['text'] . " --> ";
                    echo "<td>Tel. ". $zeile['number'] . "";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";

                    $adCounter = $adCounter+1;

                    if($adCounter > 10){
                        echo '<div class="adsDiv"></div>';
                        echo '<div class="adsDiv"></div>'; 
                    }
                }
                echo "</table>";

                mysqli_free_result( $db_erg );
                mysqli_close($db_link);
            ?>
```

this is the message I Get

> Good: Veza uspesno postavljena sa Serverom:
>
> mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd
>   5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $ [client_version] => 50012 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] =>
>   [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0
>   [host_info] => sql302.epizy.com via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0
>   [server_info] => 5.6.41-84.1 [server_version] => 50641 [stat] =>
>   Uptime: 5082420 Threads: 8 Questions: 732608614 Slow queries: 6316
>   Opens: 5723522 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 10000 Queries per second
>   avg: 144.145 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id]
>   => 18480269 [warning_count] => 0 )
>
> Error: Ungültige Abfrage:

Comment: I can see an SQL syntax error straight away `SELECT * MYSQL_DATENBANK` is missing `FROM` ... so your query is failing and you're getting the error. You're also going to have an issue with the query since it appears `MYSQL_DATENBANK` is supposed to be a constant which means you can't interpolate it into your query like you are, you'll need to break the string `"SELECT * FROM " . MYSQL_DATENBANK . " ... "`

Comment: "i do not know what i am doing wrong" - you need to configure the proper error reporting for both PHP and mysqli. Then PHP *will tell you* what are you doing wrong.

Comment: @CD001
 i changed it now to this

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . MYSQL_DATENBANK . " ORDER BY date 
        DESC LIMIT 30";

I cannot read from it yet, when I change MYSQL_DATENBANK to the name of database for example db_test, than it will work.
Thanks so much i've been looking yesterday & today for the error